# How to define a list of object for SecurityGroups for ec2 SpotFleet instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have below cloudformation template, it defines a `spotfleet` ec2 instance with a security groups.

```
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Description: The EC2 Key Pair to allow SSH access to the instance
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName'
Resources:
  Ec2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SpotFleet'
    Properties:
      SpotFleetRequestConfigData:
        AllocationStrategy: lowestPrice
        SpotPrice: 1
        LaunchSpecifications:
          - InstanceType: p2.8xlarge
            KeyName: !Ref KeyName
            ImageId: ami-07d0cf3af28718ef8
            SecurityGroups:
              - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable SSH access via port 22
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

But I got this error when create the stack: `Value of property SecurityGroups must be a list of objects`. I wonder why `SecurityGroups` is not a list of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

After checking the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-spotfleet.html#aws-resource-ec2-spotfleet--examples) it seems like you have to specify an array of [`GroupIdentifier`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-spotfleet-spotfleetrequestconfigdata-launchspecifications-securitygroups.html):

```
    SecurityGroups:
    - GroupId:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - InstanceSecurityGroup
        - GroupId
```

---

Old answer:

I think you have to specify `!Ref MyExistingSecurityGroup` instead of `MyExistingSecurityGroup`.

Comment: I delete the line `MyExistingSecurityGroup` from the template but still have the same issue.